# Install Subversion 1.7.x on SLES 11 SP3

Tags: svn, suse, zypper

Is there a way to install `Subversion 1.7.x` on `SLES 11 SP3`? I only found repos/links/downloads for `SVN 1.8.x`. (http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=devel:tools:scm:svn&package=subversion)

I tried to just add the repository for `SLES 11 SP2` or `SLES 11`, but `zypper` refresh told me, that it couldn't find valid meta-data for those repository-urls...